# Perl - evaluation order of list elements, with assignment inside the list

Tags: perl, evaluation

According to Perldoc( https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Comma-Operator ):

> Comma Operator
>
> ...
>
> In list context, it's just the list argument separator, and inserts both its arguments into the list. These arguments are also **evaluated from left to right.**

In following code, I thought `$n` should be `1` but it became `2`. What am I missing?

```
my $v = 1;
my $n = ( $v, $v = 2 )[0];
# I thought left "$v" would be evaluated (and return 1) first, then right "$v = 2" would.
say "n = $n";  # but output was 2
say "v = $v";  # 2
```

or

```
my $v = 1;
my @l = ( $v, $v = 2 );
say Dumper(\@l);   # [ 2, 2 ], not [ 1, 2 ]
```

even when I changed the order:

```
my $v = 1;
# my $n = ( $v, $v = 2 )[0];
my $n = ( $v = 2, $v )[1];
say "n = $n";  # still 2
say "v = $v";  # 2
```

Comment: `my $n = ( "$v", $v = 2 )[0];` works which shows that $v is not evaluated to its value when you think it is.

Comment: @choroba Thanks, I tried `$v1+0` and it worked as expected too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does get evaluated left-to-right.

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'my $v = 1; my $n = ( $v, $v = 2 )[0];'
1  <0> enter v
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  <$> const[IV 1] s                   \
4  <0> padsv[$v:1,3] sRM*/LVINTRO       > my $v = 1;
5  <2> sassign vKS/2                   /
6  <;> nextstate(main 2 -e:1) v:{
7  <0> pushmark s                                  \              \
8  <$> const[IV 0] s                               |              |
9  <0> pushmark s                                  |              |
a  <0> padsv[$v:1,3] s                    $v       > ( ... )[0]   |
b  <$> const[IV 2] s                   \           |              > my $n = ...
c  <0> padsv[$v:1,3] sRM*               > $v = 2   |              |
d  <2> sassign sKS/2                   /           |              |
e  <2> lslice sK/2                                /               |
f  <0> padsv[$n:2,3] sRM*/LVINTRO                                 |
g  <2> sassign vKS/2                                             /
h  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

The catch is that the scalar associated with `$v` is placed on the stack, not the integer. You can see what's happening here:

```perl
use 5.014;
use warnings;

my @stack;

sub sassign {
   my $rhs = pop(@stack);
   my $lhs = pop(@stack);
   $$rhs = $$lhs;
   push @stack, $rhs;
}
                       # Stack     $v   $n
                       # -------   --   --
push @stack, \1;       # 1
push @stack, \my $v;   # 1,$v      !d
sassign();             # $v        1
@stack = ();           #           1

push @stack, \$v;      # $v        1

push @stack, \2;       # $v,2      1
push @stack, \$v;      # $v,2,$v   1
sassign();             # $v,$v     2

pop(@stack);           # $v        2          # Net result of slice.
push @stack, \my $n;   # $v,$n     2    !d
sassign();             # $n        2    2
@stack = ();           #           2    2

say $n;  # 2
```

If you prefer aliases over references:

```perl
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use experimental qw( refaliasing declared_refs );

my @stack;

sub sassign {
   my \$rhs = \pop(@stack);
   my \$lhs = \pop(@stack);
   $rhs = $lhs;
   \$stack[@stack] = \$rhs;
}
                            # Stack     $v   $n
                            # -------   --   --
\$stack[@stack] = \1;       # 1
\$stack[@stack] = \my $v;   # 1,$v      !d
sassign();                  # $v        1
@stack = ();                #           1

\$stack[@stack] = \$v;      # $v        1

\$stack[@stack] = \2;       # $v,2      1
\$stack[@stack] = \$v;      # $v,2,$v   1
sassign();                  # $v,$v     2

pop(@stack);                # $v        2          # Net result of slice.
\$stack[@stack] = \my $n;   # $v,$n     2    !d
sassign();                  # $n        2    2
@stack = ();                #           2    2

say $n;  # 2
```

Comment: Wow... thank you so much for such detail. While I can't understand the output of B::Concise, the second code in Perl was ease to understand. Now I know what happened inside. However, I still think this behavior is somewhat weird(?). isn't it?

Comment: Do you find the following weird?: 
$v =0; f($v, $v); sub f { $_[0]++; $_[1]++ }; print $v; # prints 2

Comment: @gypark, No, I don't find `$v` putting the scalar `$v` on the stack weird. What's weird is the code posted. Weird code doing unexpected things is not weird.

Comment: @DaveMitchell Do I don't, because I know the elements of `@_` are aliases for the arguments from `perldoc perlsub`. :) Maybe I should have read more docs for my question.